# Datepart Week Sql (With 53 weeks for year)

Tags: sql, datepart

I'm calculating the week for a specific date in SQL for example 
'2016-01-20' (`yyyy-mm-dd`) but SQL returns week: 4, and that is wrong because this year the first week started on '2016-01-04' the result must be week: 3.

I think the issue is generatad because 2015 was a year with 53 weeks, any solution to that? Thank you and I'm sorry for my bad English

Comment: To clarify your question, please list the following: 1) The Database you are using the datepart function (SQL Server or MS Access); 2) The specific query you are writing; 3) The results or error you are seeing; 4) The results you are expecting to see.

Comment: If this is SQL Server then `January 1 of any year defines the starting number for the week datepart, for example: DATEPART (wk, 'Jan 1, xxxx') = 1, where xxxx is any year.` -msdn

Comment: What RDBMS are you using: SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle ... ? It makes a difference to the answer.

Comment: Assuming SQL Server - perhaps you are looking for the datepart option `ISO_WEEK`? [Here is some light reading](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38680/iso-week-vs-sql-server-week)

Comment: Calculating "week in year" is highly (if not incredibly) subjective. If your business requirements do not match those of your RDBMS, you will have to "roll your own" logic.

Comment: According to your question, weeks start on Mondays.  If that's your business situation you may want to create a calendar table that includes this sort of thing.  We have one in our data warehouse and the field is called week_beginning.

Comment: Based on the question the OP definition of a week is based on ISO.

Answer (score 0):

In tSQL the `DATEPART()` is returning the correct data based on US and Most of Europe as well as UK See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

You can use `SET DATEFIRST` to adjust the start position however.

Comment: The OP needs to use `ISO_WEEK`. And BOL are plain wrong, ISO weeks are common across Europe, not only *Norway and Sweden* (and other parts of the world, too)

Answer (score 0):

The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the year's first Thursday in it. I am using Intersystems cache which apparently does not account for that either. So I have used this to address that

```
CASE WHEN 7-datepart(dw,dateadd(dd,1,dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,0,getdate())-1,0))) < 2 
THEN datepart(wk,getdate())-1 ELSE datepart(wk,getdate()) END as WeekNum
```